# How to initialize cockpit on CentOS8?

Tags: linux, centos, amazon-ec2, centos7, centos8

I am trying to access my public IP of the EC2- box on port 9090 to access centOS8 cockpit but I am unable to get to my centOS8 cockpit.

My security group from the server is [Security group](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LU3Ue.jpg)

This is what I have when I run sudo **firewall-cmd --list-all**

```
public (active)
  target: default
  icmp-block-inversion: no
  interfaces: eth0 eth1
  sources: 
  services: cockpit dhcpv6-client ssh
  ports: 9090/tcp 9090/udp
  protocols: 
  forward: no
  masquerade: no
  forward-ports: 
  source-ports: 
  icmp-blocks: 
  rich rules:
```

Comment: In security groups add port 9090/TCP

Comment: I added it to the security groupp 9090/TCP and 9090/UDP. still can't access it

Comment: Check if `cockpit` is running: `netstat -an|grep 9090`

Comment: Yes, it is running and listening on 9090.

Comment: Did you bind the security group to EC2?

Comment: How would you suggest to bind the security group to ec2?

Comment: I updated my question with an updated screenshot